# App Badge for Sony z3

Tags: android, push-notification, badge

I'm trying no use ShortcutBadger to make number of my notification on the left of my app icon. When I try with Galaxy Tab2, S6 and LG G4, everthing is fine, but with Sony Z3 wasn't anything happen. Had anyone met that case? Many thanks.
Link to lib: https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Comment: Which version you are using, there is some known issue with sony prior to 1.1.6 version.

Comment: I use 1.1.7 version, but when I try on my Sony C4 it's ok